# Check if img src is empty using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="previewWrapper" id="thumbPreview3">
  <div class="previewContainer">
   <img src="" class="photoPreview" data-width="" data-height=""><span>3</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And I have the following JQUERY which isn't working.

```
    if($('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img').attr('src') == '') {
      alert('got me');
    }
```

can anyone advise what I'm missing.
What to get the click event to work when the src is empty.

thx

Comment: seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/44W2s/

Comment: did u put that inside the $(document).ready()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img[src=='']").click(function()){
          alert('got me');
        }
});
```

Comment: He asked how to "get" the click event, too. `$("div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img[src=='']").click(function() { alert('got me'); });`

Answer (score 6):

You should do your verification inside document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img').attr('src') == '') { 
      alert('got me'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap this in document.ready function like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img').attr('src') == '')
     {
      alert('got me');
    }


});
```

Comment: that will check the first image attribute src only.

Answer (score 2):

Please Check this It seems working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/EQrWs/)

```
<div class="previewWrapper" id="thumbPreview3">
  <div class="previewContainer">
   <img src="" class="photoPreview" data-width="" data-height=""><span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id=click value =" Click me" />


$(function () {

    $("#click").click(function () {

        if ($('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img').attr('src') == '') {
            alert('got me');
        }
    });


});​
```

Comment: It's better to post the sample code here, too. JSFiddle may disappear one day.